# No Warning About Intermediate Edits While Rolling Back

Tags: feature-request, edits, rollbacks

I noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18326904/revisions) which had a suggested edit approved which broke some of the formatting in the post and didn't add any particular value to the post. I went to rollback to revision 2 which was a good edit, however in between my loading the post history and performing the rollback another user also edited the post. There was no warning letting me know that there had been another edit in the interim like there is with editing a post, it just rolled the post back overriding that intermediate edit.

Can a warning be added for cases like this where an edit has been made between loading the edit history and performing a rollback?

Comment: I remember this post; it had let me edit it even though I was still in the context of the suggested edits queue. I hadn't known three edits had already been made to it!

Comment: Does the other user's edit that you rolled over appear in the edit history?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, revision 2 is the first edit, revision 3 is the bad edit, revision 4 is the intermediate edit after I loaded the edit history, and then revision 5 is my rollback to revision 2.

Comment: OK, so which edit is the good one?  If the edit you stomped on is in the edit history, you can "roll back" to it (which is really a roll-forward), and it will fix the problem.

Comment: I think this is a [meta-tag:feature-request] rather than [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: @JanDvorak how so? A feature request means that the intention of the developers was to do that. A bug is when it's unintentional. I doubt the developers thought "oh, let's make rollbacks not warn about intermediate edits!", but then again, they _are_ programmers...

Comment: @ColeJohnson if it ain't broke, it ain't a bug. It isn't technically broken, it just lacks the feature of an automatic update - or at least revision checking while performing roll backs.

Comment: @JanDvorak got me there. I guess you're right

Comment: @RobertHarvey it will fix the issue, but you still even have an indication that you rolled back more than you intended.

Comment: The problem is also with the robo reviewers who approved that bad edit in the first place.